# Sizing for Azure Chat bot when using Azure Web App for one Chat bot user

Tags: botframework

What is the sizing required for Azure Chat Bot service when using Azure WebApp when one user is logged in using chat service

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Service pricing is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-service/). There are two plans, FREE and Standard. If you send and reply messages to your bot more than 10,000 times/month, you should choose the Standard plan. But if you use only standard channels, you could choose the Free plan. The Standard channels are Microsoft first-party services (such as Skype, Cortana and Microsoft Teams) and services with publicly available Bot API’s (such as Facebook and Slack).

You also need to size the [App Service Plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/). If you don't need bot availability, you could choose the FREE plan.